# Rails Ajax query data before reloading page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

So I am trying to find a better way of refreshing the page. I have an app that builds an Excel spreadsheet using data you capture on the system. So what I was having it do is just reloading the page every 10 seconds till it's completed, so that the notice could be displayed properly.

Something like this (it's in the HAML syntax)

```
.pending_downloads
  - if downloads_policy.pending?
    .notification_notice
      = image_tag 'spinner.gif'
      Your data download is being prepared. This should only take a few minutes. It is safe to leave this page and return later.
      = link_to "Cancel download.", download_path(downloads_policy.pending), :method => :delete, :class => "delete_link"
    = javascript_tag("ToolkitApplication.periodical_reload();")
```

The Ajax (it's in coffeescript) for the `periodical_reload();` method looks like this:

```
class @ToolkitApplication
  this.periodical_reload = () ->
    setInterval (->
      window.location.reload()
    ), 10000
```

This approach I feel could be done better. I would like to have the ajax rather query the model every 3 seconds to see when the objects state has changed and then once it has changed then it will reload the window. So you dont get the page reloading like 10 times before the download is ready, every time I try reasearch if this is possible I get this [rubyonrails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) which isnt really insightful with this sort of edge case. Is this possible and if so is there any good tutorials/blog posts/advice on how to do this? Google is yielding nothing.

Comment: Periodical reloading is something you should not even think of using in any form of application. It confuses the user and renders the application unprofessional (atleast IMHO). You should `setInterval` to check at server if data is ready or not. If it is ready and user is at the same page, then simply update the block of view that displays the result. Or upon successful completion of task, show a popup or Linux-like Alerts notifying the user that the said task is completed. Also, don't forget to `clearInterval` at that time. In the alert, provide a link to take user to result.

Comment: yeah that is what i am looking at doing the page will have to refresh because there is table that will refresh as well. but i 100% agree. the part thats catching me is using ajax to query server data. i am using respond_to |format| then format.js to try catch it but this is confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i ended up doing was easy. Thanks to all that helped. in my controller i set a `private` method to check state

```
def any_uploads_status_changes?
  return true if !Upload.exists?(params[:id])
  return true if Upload.find(params[:id]).status
end
```

And then set another call in the controller called status:

```
def status
  if any_uploads_status_changes?
    render :text => 'window.location.reload();'
  else
    render :nothing => true
  end
end
```

then set up an ajax request method(its in coffeescript syntax) ->

```
this.periodically_send_ajax_request = (url, method, interval) ->
  setInterval (->
    $.ajax
      url: url
      type: method
      success: (result) ->

  ), interval
```

And then in the view just under condition called this request using js:

```
:javascript
  ToolkitApplication.periodically_send_ajax_request("#{status_download_path(:id => downloads_policy.pending.id, :class => @model_class).html_safe }",'get', 2000);
```

just make sure that the path exists to the controller action

```
resources :downloads, :only => [:show, :destroy] do
  member do
    get :status
  end
end
```

and there you go it will then query the controller according to what ever interval you specify and only if there are changes will it then reload the page. its a bit more code then simply reloading periodically but the user will appreciate it! :)